# Django: How do I display this variable information in models to my template

Tags: python, django

I want to display answer subject and question in my template. How would I call these variables from my Answer class in my template?

Here is how my class looks

Model.py:

```
  class Answer(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, help_text = u'The user who supplied this answer')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, help_text = u"The question that this is an answer to")
    runid = models.CharField(u'RunID', help_text = u"The RunID (ie. year)", max_length=32)
    answer = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Answer(%s: %s, %s)" % (self.question.number, self.subject.surname, self.subject.givenname)

    def choice_str(self, secondary = False):
        choice_string = ""
        choices = self.question.get_choices()

        for choice in choices:
            for split_answer in self.split_answer():
                if str(split_answer) == choice.value:
                    choice_string += str(choice.text) + " "
```

Template:

```
{{ subject }}
{{ question }}
{{ answer }}?????
```

I am fairly new to Django and I am only a few weeks in to learning.

Answer (score 0):

Values to the template are passed onto by [views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/views/) (through something known as a `context`) when they render some html, and not by the model classes as you seem to be indicating.

This also makes sense because model classes are just a schema or a representation of your database, whereas views are functions that retrieve values from the database (or not) and create dynamic content to be rendered.

Here's the link to the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something) on how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the values in your views.py something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def display_variables(request):
     subject = # get your subject and assign it a variable
     question = # get your question and assign it a variable
     answer = # get your answerand assign it a variable

     return render_to_response('your_web_page.html',{'subject':subject,'question ':question ,'answer ':answer },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```